# Why is voltage not affected by wire length even though it is mathematically given as ($V=E\cdot d$), for a wire of length $d$?

Tags: electric-fields, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, conductors

If there is $1C$ charge in other side of a battery, the potential being $$V = k\frac{q_1q_2}{r}$$

should change as $r$ changes.

Comment: Check your equation for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage between two points on a current-carrying wire is indeed affected by the distance. If one end of your wire is defined at 12 V, and the other end is 0V, for example, the voltage difference is 12V. If you measure only across half the wire, the voltage difference will be only 6V. And a quarter of the wire would be 3V. I believe this is the reason that birds don't get electrocuted while standing on wires -- their feet are so close together that the potential difference across them is very small, such that no current will flow. The equation you provide gives the electric potential between two source charges $q_1$ and $q_2$, which is not directly/easily translatable to concepts involving a wire.

[image]

Comment: ...because any wire has a resistance, too.

Comment: Out of interest, is this an African or a European swallow?

Answer (score 1):

(a) The pd, $V_0$, between the battery terminals (assuming negligible internal resistance) is determined by chemical processes at the battery's electrodes.

(b) These processes do indeed cause charges ±*Q* to reside on the terminals, but to try to derive the electric field strength in a wire joining the terminals by applying $\vec E=\frac {Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2}\hat r$, or the potential at a point along the wire using $ V=\frac {Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r}$, is futile because...

(c) The charges are not point-like nor spherically symmetrically distributed.

(d) More importantly the electric field is modified (we could even say 'controlled') by the presence of the wire. Charge conservation ensures equal current all along the wire, and according to Ohm's law, an electric field that is constant in magnitude. The magnitude of the field strength in a uniform wire of length $l$ is given by $E=V_0/l$, so the potential drop over a length $\Delta x$ is $\Delta V = E \Delta x = \frac{\Delta x}{l}V_0$.

(e) So we have an electric field that is constant in magnitude but is parallel to the wire; if the wire wiggles, the field direction wiggles with it. This extraordinary field must arise in the last analysis from a distribution of charges. As we've seen, it is not enough to consider just the charges on the battery terminals; for a full understanding we would need to examine charges on the surface of the wire itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you connect a wire to the poles, the voltages on both poles become equal. That is if the resistance of the wire is zero. Which I assume is what you mean. But how can this be? Why do the electrons flow if there is no potential difference? Well, it's precisely *because* of this flowing that the difference is zero. The only thing that stops the current from flowing is the internal voltage of the battery. The inner voltages of the battery don't become equal as it is maintained constant by chemical reactions. It is this field that is sent into the wire that keeps the electrons flowing. These voltages push and pull the electrons. The electrons move in such a way as to give a zero voltage at the poles and a zero field in the wire.
But why do the electrons flow if the field is zero? Same as for the voltage not being present. As soon as the electrons stop flowing a field builds up to make them going again. So the flow is consistent with a zero field inside the wire and zero voltage at the poles (and in the wire).
Why isn't the voltage of the poles not the same as the internal voltages? Same answer. The poles become part of the wire and only on the inside of the battery two potentials are found. The potentials (the potent ones) are the ones due to the chemical reactions.